# mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string?

Tags: php

where is the problem ? Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong here?

> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array
>   given in

```
//submit
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $user=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
    $link=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['link']);
    $subject=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['subject']);
        // required
    if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['link']) && !empty($_POST['subject'])){
        // captcha
    if (!empty($_POST["captcha"])&&$_POST["captcha"]!="" && $_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"]) {
        //inserting
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contact (`user`,`email`,`link`,`subject`)VALUES('$user','$email','$link','$subject')";
```

full code

```
 <?php
echo '
<main><section><form method="POST" class="contact-form">
  <span><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>contact</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-user form-icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" required name="user" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-at form-icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email" required  name="email"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-link form-icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="link" required name="link"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="img-capatcha" src="captcha.php">
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-paper-plane form-icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="captcha" required name="captcha" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope form-icon"></i>
      <textarea placeholder="subject" rows="2" required name="subject"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit" value="ارسال" required name="submit"/>
    </li>
  </ul></form>
  ';
//submit
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $user=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
    $link=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['link']);
    $subject=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['subject']);
        // required
    if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['link']) && !empty($_POST['subject'])){
        // captcha
    if (!empty($_POST["captcha"])&&$_POST["captcha"]!="" && $_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"]) {
        //inserting
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contact (`user`,`email`,`link`,`subject`)VALUES('$user','$email','$link','$subject')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($result) {
    echo "
    <div id='oops'>
      <div id='succ'>
        <p><i class='fas fa-check'></i>succ</p>
      </div>
    </div>";
    }
    else{
    echo "
    <div id='oops'>
      <div id='alert'>
        <p><i class='fas fa-times'></i>error in inserting</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    ";
    }
    }
    else{
    echo
    "<div id='oopss'>
      <div id='warning'>
        <p><i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle'></i>error in captcha</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    ";
    }
    }
    else{
    echo
    "<div id='oopss'>
      <div id='warning'>
        <p><i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle'></i>all input required  </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    ";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

connect code

```
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$password = "123456789"; 
$dbname = "test";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
```

Comment: print_r($_POST) check what r u getting , second `$con` check where you defined this ... u must need to prevent your code with SQL injection.

Comment: Could you show your form code?

Comment: Do you have brackets in the `name` attribute of any of your form inputs? Like, `<input type="text" name="link[]">` ? If so, that will cause the `$_POST` value to be an array instead of a string.

Comment: no just simple form

Comment: again, `$con` where you define this ??????????

Comment: i added the code of  connect to the database

Comment: did u included this connection before `if ($_POST['submit']) {`

Comment: yes i   included this connection before if all the code

Comment: its difficult to share the solution, please share the complete code which included connection and form

Comment: The code is normal but the problem is found in error_log

Comment: use `if (!$con) {
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
}
exit;` after `$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);` line and share the result

Comment: Try removing each of the `mysqli_real_escape_string` lines one by one until the error goes away. That should let you know which one if failing.

Comment: did u tried ??  ?

Comment: problem not in the connect or myqsli_real i think problem is in the localhost
appserv

Comment: what is the line concerned by the error ?